# How to add 2 columns in numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an numpy ndarray like below:

```
[[1 9 1 1]
 [9 3 1 1]
 [1 9 9 1]
 [8 2 4 7]]
```

I want to add last 2 columns values to get below result

```
[[1 9 2]
 [9 3 2]
 [1 9 10]
 [8 2 11]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sum, then drop the last column

```
myArray[:, -2] = myArray[:,-2] + myArray[:,-1] 
myArray = myArray[:,:-1]
```