# Numpy merge 2 columns values

Tags: python, numpy, merge

Let's say I have this numpy array:

```
[[3 2 1 5]
 [3 2 1 5]
 [3 2 1 5]
 [3 2 1 5]]
```

How to merge the values of the last column into the first column (or any column to any column). Expected output:

```
[[8 2 1]
 [8 2 1]
 [8 2 1]
 [8 2 1]]
```

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61092396/6013016) solution. But, is there any better way than that?

Comment: What is wrong with the answer you linked?

Comment: Size of array is immutable so creation a copy or view with different size is compulsory. A solution linked uses a view which is usually faster than copy, it might work well.

Comment: Plus it is nicely readable. "Fancy" NumPy oneliners tend to become unreadable fast...

Answer (score 1):

As per comment, you need to create a view or copy of array in order to get a new array with different size. This is a short comparison of performance of view vs copy:

```
x = np.tile([1,3,2,4],(4,1))
def f(x):
    # calculation + view
    x[:,0] = x[:,0] + x[:,-1]
    return x[:,:-1]

def g(x):
    # calculation + copy
    x[:,0] = x[:,0] + x[:,-1]
    return np.delete(x,-1, 1)

def h(x):
    #calculation only
    x[:,0] = x[:,0] + x[:,-1]

%timeit f(x)
%timeit g(x)
%timeit h(x)

9.16 µs ± 1.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
35 µs ± 7.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
7.81 µs ± 1.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

And if `len(x)` were = 1M:

```
6.13 ms ± 623 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
18 ms ± 2.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
5.83 ms ± 720 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So solution in a link is very economic, it applies calculation + instant view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best, but it's kind of clever.

```
In [66]: np.add.reduceat(arr[:,[0,3,1,2]], [0,2,3], axis=1)
Out[66]: 
array([[8, 2, 1],
       [8, 2, 1],
       [8, 2, 1]])
```

`reduceat` applies `add` to groups of columns (axis 1).  I first reordered the columns to put the ones to be added together.

Comment: don't want to be deconstructive here, but this reads more complicated and is slower in execution in comparison to the "straight forward" solution. It's "different", I give you that, but better...?