# How to group and multiply every n elements in each row?

Tags: python, numpy

Given a matrix (example)

```
a = np.array([[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
              [6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 9]])
```

How could I group every two values in the rows and multiply them to obtain:

```
[[12 30 56]
[42 72 0]]
```

Yes I need to multiply every 2 colums

Comment: I don't think 7 * 8 == 15.

Comment: `a[:,::2]*a[:,1::2]` should do the trick.

Comment: I think the question is not so bad and easily salvageable. I nominate to reopen it.

Comment: A similar question (and answer) is still open, https://stackoverflow.com/q/64692685/901925

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.multiply.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) with the right indices:

```
np.multiply.reduceat(a, np.arange(0, a.shape[1], 2), axis=1)
array([[12, 30, 56],
       [42, 72,  0]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Honestly this is a bad answer to a bad question. This is not the expected output given in the question. Besides you seem to have edited the question and changed "add" to "multiply". We don't know if it's the statement or the output that is wrong.

Comment: Well, all values except from `15` match the output you get by multiplying @Selcuk . So I think it makes more sense to assume the expected output is a multiplication

Comment: I would _guess_ the same, but wouldn't post an answer based on that.

Comment: Okay, not sure that my guess justifies a dwnvote though, but to each their own